# How to handle call to __setattr__ from __init__?

Tags: python

I have written a class that will be used to store parameters in a convenient way for pickling. It overloads `__setattr__` for convenient access. It also uses a list to remember the order in which attributes where added, so that the iteration order is predictable and constant. Here it is:

```
class Parameters(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._paramOrder = []

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self._paramOrder.append(name)
        object.__setattr__(self, name, value)

    def __delattr__(self, name):
        self._paramOrder.remove(name)
        object.__delattr__(self, name)

    def __iter__(self):
        for name in self._paramOrder:
            yield self.name

    def iteritems(self):
        for name in self._paramOrder:
            yield name, self.name
```

The problem is that `__init__` calls my overloaded `__setattr__` in order to add the `_paramOrder` to the instance dictionary. Is there a way to handle this without adding a special case to `__setattr__`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

yes.

have it call `super(Parameters, self).__setattr__()` instead.

```
class Parameters(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Parameters, self).__setattr__('paramOrder', [])

    # etc.
```

Or am I missing something?

Another alternative is to just go straight to `__dict__`

```
class Parameters(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__['paramOrder'] = []

    # etc.
```

This should work because you are not overriding `__getattr__` so you can read it without anything getting in the way.

Comment: I do that right now, but I still need a special case, because otherwise the name `_paramOrder` will be added to `_paramOrder`.

Comment: that's not the code you showed. This should bypass `Parameters`'s `__setattr__` method.

Answer (score 4):

Use this line in `__init__` instead:

```
object.__setattr__(self, '_paramOrder', [])
```